# How can I fix module not found errors with a Vue3 with CesiumJS and Webpack app?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, cesiumjs, webpack-5

I have a sample project which reproduces the issue at [vueces](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/vueces)

I created this project by doing:

```
0. vue create vueces
1. remove unnecessary stuff
2. yarn add cesium
```

the [HelloWorld.vue](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/vueces/blob/main/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) is:

```
  <div ref="cesiumContainer" id="cesiumContainer">
    hello
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Viewer } from "cesium";
import "cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css";

const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer");

console.log( "viewer", viewer)
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

When I try to build the project I get the following errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/eric/depot/tmp/vueces/node_modules/@cesium/engine/Source/Core'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/eric/depot/tmp/vueces/node_modules/@cesium/engine/Source/Core'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/Users/eric/depot/tmp/vueces/node_modules/@cesium/engine/Source/Core'
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/eric/depot/tmp/vueces/node_modules/@cesium/engine/Source/Core'
```

They all suggest the following:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }
```

I did try adding a [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/vueces/blob/webpackconfig/webpack.config.js) with:

```
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {
  return {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        url: false,
        zlib: false,
        https: false,
        http: false,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the errors persist.

I am not exactly sure what I need to change to implement this suggestion.

What do I need to change so the project will build?

Are these modules required by CesiumJS?

Answer (score 0):

Since you set up a Vue project, you can add your [Webpack options](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#working-with-webpack) in `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        "https": false,
        "zlib": false,
        "http": false,
        "url": false
      }
    }
    ...
  }
})
```

Additionally, some Cesium-specific Webpack options, which can be found at a [Cesium-Webpack template](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-webpack-example/blob/main/webpack.config.js), need to be inserted into `vue.config.js`:

```
const cesiumSource = "node_modules/cesium/Source";
const cesiumWorkers = "../Build/Cesium/Workers";
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  ...
  configureWebpack: {
    ...
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: path.join(cesiumSource, cesiumWorkers), to: "Workers" }, 
          { from: path.join(cesiumSource, "Assets"), to: "Assets" }, 
          { from: path.join(cesiumSource, "Widgets"), to: "Widgets" }, 
          { from: path.join(cesiumSource, "ThirdParty"), to: "ThirdParty" }
        ]
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        CESIUM_BASE_URL: JSON.stringify("")
      })
    ]
  }
})
```

Finally, one needs to wait until the div element, where the globe is attached to, is available in the `HelloWorld.vue` component using a [Vue lifecycle hook](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted):

```
<template>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { Viewer, Ion } from "cesium";
  import { onMounted } from "vue";
  import "cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css";

  Ion.defaultAccessToken = "<your access token>";

  onMounted(() => {
    const viewer = new Viewer("cesiumContainer");
    ...
  })
</script>
```